# Is it possible to create 3D face model using ARKit

Tags: ios, 3d, augmented-reality, arkit

Is it possible to create 3D face model using true depth camera of iPhoneX and ARKit, has anyone tried? Let me know if possible, also if there are any other libraries to do it.

I am trying to create 3D model of face and trying to place objects on it.

Comment: did you find anything?

Comment: No, let me know here if you find anything relevant to that.